# Interior of $T=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 :1>y>x^2\}\cup \{(1,0),(-1,0)\}$ How can I show the set is open without the two addition.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Problem is I cannot show that $T=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 :1>y>x^2\}$ is an open set.

Attempt:

Let take $(x_0,y_0)$ so at this center, how should I choose the radius, I can just say that $r(x)=\inf\{||x-z||\in\mathbb R:z \in T \}$ and there exists $B(x,r(x))$ st $B\subset T$ but I guess I should give concrete $r,B$ because I know T and I should talk about the example, not too general.

Moreover, how can I visualize that kind of sets? Given in the form of inequalities of two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: note that $T$ can be written as

$$
T = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 > y \} \cap \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y - x^2 > 0 \}.
$$

Now, recall that the sets $(-\infty , 1)$ and $(0, +\infty)$ are open, and the functions 
$$
f(x,y) = y, \\ g(x,y) = y -x^2
$$
are continuous.

Comment: we can say $(0,\infty)$ for the right set and use $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ but what if we had another $g(x,y)=u(y)+v(x)$ then how can I find the S where $g^{-1}(S)$

Comment: That depends on the particular case you are working with. As you said, here we get $T = f^{-1}(-\infty, 1) \cap g^{-1}(0,+\infty)$.